# Maximum call stack size exceeded reported by Auguri in my Angular 10 application

Tags: angular

I have implemented the routing for my Angular 10 application and routing works fine. When i inspect Auguri , I see the following error.

[image]

I have implemented the routing in a way, where customerdetailscomponent is eagerly loaded and CustomerOrderscomponent is lazy loaded. When I route to either of these components , get the error. I am unable to understand why I am getting this error

App.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'CustomerManager-Client';
}
```

AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CustomerModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

CustomerModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomerDetailsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

CustomerDetailsComponent

```
export class CustomerDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
customerDetails: ICustomerDetails[];

  constructor(private customerDetailsService: CustomerDetailsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerDetails();
  }

  getCustomerDetails(): void {
    this.customerDetailsService.getCustomerDetails()
            .subscribe(data => this.customerDetails = data);

  }
}
```

OrderModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomerOrdersComponent,
    OrderDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrderRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class OrderModule { }
```

OrderRoutingModule

```
const orderRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'orderDetails', component: OrderDetailsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(orderRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule { }
```

CustomerOrder

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './customer-orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-orders.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerOrdersComponent implements OnInit {

  customerOrders: ICustomerOrders[];

  constructor(private customerOrdersService: CustomerOrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerOrders();
  }


  getCustomerOrders(): void {
      this.customerOrdersService.getCustomerOrders().subscribe( data => this.customerOrders = data);
  }

}
```

CustomerOrderService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CustomerOrdersService extends BaseService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, private customerOrdersEndpoint: CustomerOrdersEndpointService){
    super(http);
   }

   getCustomerOrders(): Observable<ICustomerOrders[]> {
       return  this.http.get<ICustomerOrders[]>(this.customerOrdersEndpoint.getCustomerOrders(), this.getRequestHeaders()) ;
   }
}
```

CustomerOrderServiceEndpoint

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerOrdersEndpointService extends BaseService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
   }

   getCustomerOrders(): string {
      return `${this.baseUrl}/api/customer-orders`;
   }
}
```

Base service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {

  baseUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

  protected getRequestHeaders(): {headers: HttpHeaders | {[header: string ]: string | string[]; }} {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           Accept: `application/json, text/plain, */*`,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'
      });
      return {headers};
  }
}
```

Comment: would you mind to put this in stackblitz?

Comment: just for debugging, try to mock the data of `CustomerDetailsService.getCustomerDetails`

Comment: If you're getting a maximum call stack error, it's usually because of an infinite loop.   It could also be you are calling a method in your template and its getting called over and over as well (you may want to switch to onPush if thats the case).

Comment: What do you mean by  onPush

Comment: Using the onPush ChangeDetectionStrategy for Angular.  Here is a comprehensive article on it https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: check if in the .html you has a function or you has a typo error, e.g. you want to use == and use =

Answer (score 0):

Try running this cmd:

```
npm config set max-old-space-size=1024
```

You can also increase the size if the problem persists.

Comment: problem still persist . I tried increasing upto 2024

Comment: Not sure if this is an ideal fix